# SQLite query not working when using a specific column

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have the table

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [products](
    [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    [productCategoryId] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [productMeasurementId] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [eanCode] TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    [reference] TEXT UNIQUE DEFAULT NULL,
    [shortDescription] TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    [longDescription] TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    [buyPrice] DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [sellPrice1] DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [sellPrice2] DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [sellPrice3] DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [taxPercentage] DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [sold] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [inStock] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [AmountToOrder] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [OrderWhenLessThan] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [weigth] DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [set] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY(productCategoryId) REFERENCES productCategories(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(productMeasurementId) REFERENCES productMeasurements(id)
```

And want to make a simple insert, but, any insert I try that involves the column "set" just fails (SQL error 1, which is the SQLite way of telling you "I know as much as you about this error", saying there is an error near "set")

The query is:

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [products] (productMeasurementId,shortDescription,longDescription,taxPercentage,buyPrice,sellPrice1,sellPrice2,sellPrice3,inStock,sold,OrderWhenLessThan,AmountToOrder,weigth,productCategoryId,eanCode,set,reference) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
```

All params are correct, and if I run the same query without the "set"(and removing one of the ? of course), it runs without any issue. I'm passing to set a simple 0 as parameter. I tried with 1 too (I wanted set to be Boolean but SQLite doesn't support it so integer it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` is a reserved keyword. Use backticks to escape the name.

```
insert into ... `set` ...
```

Comment: oh, didnt think keywords where case sensitive :/ i will just use other column name

Comment: @cg7.baselines it's not about case sensitivity, it's that some words CANNOT be used (irrespective of case) because they are reserved words used by SQLite. However, escaping (always) such words, albeit it not recommended, allows such words to be used.

Comment: @juergend: Please amend your answer to use double-quotes ("set") rather than back-ticks.  Back-ticks are *not* standard SQL, but double-quotes are.

Comment: @varro: I prefer backticks for SQLite because it is syntax wise related to MySQL. And in MySQL double quotes don't work.